# MCV Web application with On-Premise ADFS Authentication

Tags: authentication, adfs

really hope that I can get some pointers with this before I go wasting too much time.  In truth, I'm not even one hundred percent sure where I need to be asking this.  I'm dealing with a whole heap of technologies I've had little to know experience with.  Historically, I've been a pretty simple vb.net desktop developer so I'm learning MCV5 & C# as I go.  I realize some of this might be in the wrong place, but hoping for pointers at lease

So the situation is I've been asked to develop a web application/api by a number of my customers so that their field staff can perform certain data entry functions while out of the office and periodically feed back into their management systems.  All these customer have the very close to the same requirements and management systems, so my my intent is to build a single web application with a multi-tenant database where I control who gets to see what based on their login.
The core of the web app, database(s) etc I've got my head around, in fact that all seems pretty seamless. Using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx as a start point I think I can manage the database side of things.

Where I'm really struggling over is how best to secure this system.  Looking at the options in available to me in visual studio (2015) I think the best option for me is for me to use an On-Premise ADFS.  My boss has already put his foot down regarding Azure, so unfortunately not an option, we pretty much have our own server farm in house more than capable of hosting this.
The real sticker here is my SA has pretty much said this is not his problem, if you want ADFS and a web server, you sort it out.  He's given me a nice fresh server VM with Win2012R2 at least, but doesn't want anything more to do with it.

So, to the questions

1. Is ADFS even needed in this scenario, or am I better deal with this
   all via a standard AD or some other tooling? And even if it is possible, is it a good idea?
2. Duringdevelopment/testing, is it ok to use a self signing certificate or
   am I going to run into to trouble with certificate errors?
3. When configuring ADFS, you get asked for the federation Service name.  In
   the senario above where I'm using it for authenticating a web app,
   is it ever exposed directly to the end user?  Are they going to be
   needing to type this in to their browsers? and will it be better to have external DNS entries for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 2-cent:

1. There will be a learning curve, but if all the users are stored in AD, using ADFS will give you some advantages such as SSO, federation against other providers if you ever need it later on.
2. Using self-signed certificates during dev/test is fine. You can turn off certificate revocation check on ADFS side.
3. No, that Federation service name doesn't get exposed to the end users. I would suggest you have external DNS entries for your ADFS because your users need to access it from the outside. In short, a user rarely needs to type in ADFS url. Instead, he or she needs to access a service provider site and it will redirects he or she to the ADFS site.

Answer (score 0):

This is becoming a more common scenario and can be seamlessly handled with AD FS. Ideally what you would want to do is:

- deploy your AD FS farm
- Configure your Web Application to trust your ADFS STS
- Whenever you need to add a customer who will be using your multi-tenant application, add a federation trust with that customer (i.e. federation trust between your AD FS and the customer's AD FS)

This will ensure that you don't have to deal with identity management for every individual user when you add a customer. When a customer tries to login to your WebApp, then he will be authenticated against his AD FS, and your AD FS will get the token and sign them and present it to the Web Application. This will give them SSO which everyone has started to expect as a de-facto :)

**Self signed certificates** - As Thuan mentioned it is ok to use them during testing, just ensure that all your test boxes are configured to trust the certificate or otherwise you will be seeing connection drops all around

**Federation service name** - As explained in the setup summary above, the federation service name will never need to be exposed to the end user from a customer's organization. For all he knows, he is being authenticated against his AD FS as he is used to it already.

You might want to consider deploying AD FS in Azure:
[AD FS deployment in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-azure-adfs/)

Comment: Appreciate the comments, as I said though no matter how much I wanted to use Azure AD for this I can't.  Boss is quite certain on this.